# ESLint doesn't accept max-len rule

Tags: eslint

I try to change max-len rule:

```
module.exports = {
  'env': {
    'browser': true,
    'es2021': true,
  },
  'extends': [
    'google',
  ],
  'parserOptions': {
    'ecmaVersion': 12,
    'sourceType': 'module',
  },
  'rules': {
    "max-len": 120,
  },
  'root': true,
};
```

But it doesn't work. If i write 180 symbols per line it doesn't highlight it line.

Answer (score 1):

your configuration is not correct. the correct configuration is here: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/max-len

```json
"max-len": ["error", { "code": 120 }]
```